# VB6 datagrid empty or invisible in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, datagrid, vb6

On windows 8, I have the following problem:

In my client's old VB6 app, there is a datagrid that has 3 rows.
These rows are displayed in 3 different "shades" of yellow.
All is well until you load data into the datagrid.
The rows turn grey and no data is displayed.

Among others, the following references are used:
- Microsoft DataGrid Control 6.0 (OLEDB)
- Microsoft DataList Control 6.0 (OLEDB)
- Microsoft FlexGrid Control 6.0

Everything works just fine under Windows 7.
I should mention that we always use classic theme in Windows 7.
I tried some classic-style themes under Windows 8 but none of them fix the problem.
I also tried importing the "HKCU\control panel\colors" registry entries from W7. 
I actually don't think it's theme-related.
Also, msflxgrd.ocx and msdatgrd.ocx are present in "c:\windows\syswow64"

Any suggestions? VB6 should still be supported, so I'm not giving up hope just yet.

Comment: The VB6 DataGrid doesn't support cell colorization as far as I know.  Is this some other (3rd party?) control?  Or perhaps you are colorizing via some "back door" method and this is what is failing?

Comment: The client abandoned this approach, so i'm going to leave it at this. Thanks for your reply though!